# How is the best method to generate a url with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I will apprecaite your **help** in this topic.

I need to build a site with friendly urls using **url rewriting** in order to improve **SEO positioning**.

I've been searching torought web and finally pointing to this two main options :

1. **asp .NET with isapi extension**
2. **asp .NET mvc**

however, I got no experience on both items so I need you to help me to kwow further about this two technologies and to take the right decision for my needs.

**Thanks**

Comment: What do you mean by "ASP with ISAPI extension"? Do you mean Classic ASP? What ISAPI extension do you mean?

Comment: I think he meant that using the rewrite ISAPI extension. The old one for .Net 2.0 and under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a host/server that can run ASP.NET MVC (i.e. one that has the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 installed on it), you can use the Routing Engine (System.Web.Routing) from ASP.NET MVC in a web forms environment, Phil Haack has a good updated walkthough at ["Using Routing With WebForms"](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx).

There's also ["How to: Use Routing with Web Forms"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx) on MSDN.

Unlike an ISAPI filter, this enables you to use the routing engine to generate your internal links as well as responding to well formed links from outside.

Answer (score 1):

There are much bigger concerns than just URL setup when making this choice.  You're talking about two completely different architectures for building your web pages.

You should make the decision on how you want to build your application, what skillsets you have available in your developers, etc.  Both approaches will be able to handle the URLs that you need to generate for SEO considerations.

For public facing websites, I would personally choose ASP.Net MVC, because I find the development cycle shorter, more productive, more flexible and more maintainable than an ASP.Net webforms application.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with womp. But there is one advantage i see in Asp.Net webforms that Asp.Net Mvc doesn't have:  Rich Client Iteraction controls. Everything in Mvc in View layer is simple and functionality need to be build from scratch.

Comment: To be honest there are a large number of Rich Client interaction controls available for both ASP.NET AJAX (which plugs into ASP.NET MVC), jQuery (which is included with ASP.NET MVC) and other JavaScript libraries, which mean that you don't have to build them from scratch, and you end up with much cleaner HTML, smaller page sizes and often faster pages.

Answer (score 0):

alexserver - at the same time of course, the fit between mvc and jquery is an overwhelming reason to abandon the rich clinet controls. that way, you can literally get your designer and/or a jquery UI expert to work on the view portions in isolation whilst you craft the model and controllers.